# Using threejs for Image processing

Tags: javascript, three.js

Hi is there a way to use https://threejs.org/ for Image processing?

- Convert raw image from camera and phone camera to compressed JPEG
- Resize images and save as compressed JPEG

Comment: For example: https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/loaders/ImageLoader

Answer (score 2):

three.js is probably not the right library to use for that sort of image processing. I would start by looking for a JS library that reads RAW image files from cameras, like [dcraw](https://github.com/zfedoran/dcraw.js/) or [raw-decoder](https://www.npmjs.com/package/raw-decoder), depending on what input formats you need to support. Then compress the data with a dedicated compression library like [sharp](https://github.com/lovell/sharp) or [mozjpeg-js](https://www.npmjs.com/package/mozjpeg-js).